# Set Isolation level to DIRTY READ in Entity Framework with Informix

Tags: entity-framework-5, informix, isolation-level, dirtyread

Is there a way to set isolation levels in Entity Framework 5 with Informix database or LOCK MODE TO WAIT?

I have tried to set isolation using SQL query, at the time of DbContext object creation.

```
var dataContext = new DatabaseNameContext();  
dataContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("SET ISOLATION TO DIRTY READ");
```

But it seems this is not working. I am still getting a lock exception:

```
IBM.Data.DB2.DB2Exception (0x80004005): ERROR [IX000] [IBM][IDS/UNIX64]
Could not do a physical-order read to fetch next row.
(-107 ISAM error: record is locked.
```

I tried using TransactionScope with System.Transactions.IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted, but it is throwing the exception:

```
IBM.Data.DB2.DB2Exception (0x80004005): ERROR [58005] [IBM][IDS/UNIX64]
SQL0998N Error occurred during transaction or heuristic processing.
Reason Code = "16". Subcode = "2-8004D026".
```

Can you explain what's going wrong and how to fix it?

Comment: The second error looks like you're using the DRDA connection mechanism, rather than SQLI — is that right?  Frankly, if SET ISOLATION TO DIRTY READY is not working, I'm not sure how to get around this.  One possibility is that the code handling DRDA connections is overriding the isolation level, I'm not sure how probable that is — and it depends on the initial guess to even be a possibility (I'm not sure I'd count it as plausible).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler  Thank you for quick response. That's right, I am using DRDA connection (Entity Framework works only with DRDA port). One update though! When I tried TransactionScope by manually opening connection, it is not throwing exception, but i still see locks.

Answer (score 0):

`dataContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("SET LOCK MODE TO WAIT 20");`

It works for me :) Might be of use to someone...